# All combinations of array set values

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, combinations

I need some help in generating input for my function.

I have two sets of arrays:

**Products:**

```
$products = array('prod_1'=>1,'prod_2'=>1,'prod_3'=>1,'prod_4'=>1);
```

**Prices:**

```
$prices = array(1,2,3);
```

What i would like to get, is a loop that  would output all possible combinations of $products array populated by $prices:

**example output**

```
# array('prod_1'=>1,'prod_2'=>1,'prod_3'=>1,'prod_4'=>1);
# array('prod_1'=>2,'prod_2'=>1,'prod_3'=>1,'prod_4'=>1);
# array('prod_1'=>1,'prod_2'=>2,'prod_3'=>1,'prod_4'=>1);
# array('prod_1'=>1,'prod_2'=>1,'prod_3'=>2,'prod_4'=>1);
# array('prod_1'=>1,'prod_2'=>1,'prod_3'=>1,'prod_4'=>2);
...
# array('prod_1'=>1,'prod_2'=>2,'prod_3'=>2,'prod_4'=>1);
...
# array('prod_1'=>2,'prod_2'=>3,'prod_3'=>1,'prod_4'=>1);
...
#1 array('prod_1'=>3,'prod_2'=>1,'prod_3'=>3,'prod_4'=>2);
etc.
```

**UPDATE 1**

In my opinion it should work something like a clock:

1. Set all values in $products to first value from $prices
2. Loop thought all values from $prices for $products['prod_1']
3. When you bump the and set $products['prod_1'] to $prices[0] and do point 2 for $products['prod_2'] (index+1)
4. Do point 2 and 3 and go index+1, reset prev until all $products values are set to last $prices value

Output:

```
1,1,1,1
2,1,1,1
3,1,1,1
1,2,1,1
2,2,1,1
3,2,1,1
1,3,1,1
2,3,1,1
3,3,1,1
1,1,2,1
do it until:
3,3,3,3
```

Am in on the right track?

Comment: You've already mentioned a loop.  Give it a shot and post an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

Here's my code:

```
$t = new test();
$t->run();

class test{
   private $_data = array("p1"=>1,"p2"=>1,"p3"=>1);
   private $_values =array(1,2,3);
   private $_data_pos =0;
   private $_values_pos =0;


public function run(){
    while($this->combos()==true){
        // do sth with $this->_data
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($this->_data);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}

function combos(){
    $keys = array_keys($this->_data);
    if($this->_values_pos>count($this->_values)-1){ 
        $this->_values_pos = 0;

        while($this->_data[$keys[$this->_data_pos]]==$this->_values[count($this->_values)-1]){

            $this->_data[$keys[$this->_data_pos]] = $this->_values[0];
            $this->_data_pos++;
            if(empty($keys[$this->_data_pos])) return false;

        }
        $k = array_search($this->_data[$keys[$this->_data_pos]],$this->_values);
        $this->_data[$keys[$this->_data_pos]] = $this->_values[$k+1];
        $this->_data_pos=0;

            //return true;
    }
    $this->_data[$keys[$this->_data_pos]] = $this->_values[$this->_values_pos];

    $this->_values_pos++;

    return true;
}

}
```

It outputs:

```
array(3) {
  ["p1"]=>
  int(1)
  ["p2"]=>
  int(1)
  ["p3"]=>
  int(1)
}
array(3) {
  ["p1"]=>
  int(2)
  ["p2"]=>
  int(1)
  ["p3"]=>
  int(1)
}
array(3) {
  ["p1"]=>
  int(3)
  ["p2"]=>
  int(1)
  ["p3"]=>
  int(1)
}
array(3) {
  ["p1"]=>
  int(1)
  ["p2"]=>
  int(2)
  ["p3"]=>
  int(1)
}
array(3) {
  ["p1"]=>
  int(2)
  ["p2"]=>
  int(2)
  ["p3"]=>
  int(1)
}
array(3) {
  ["p1"]=>
  int(3)
  ["p2"]=>
  int(2)
  ["p3"]=>
  int(1)
}
array(3) {
  ["p1"]=>
  int(1)
  ["p2"]=>
  int(3)
  ["p3"]=>
  int(1)
}
```